# checking solution to ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a specific way to tell whether $x(t) = 0 $ is a solution to a differential equation ? Where 
$$ \frac {dx}{dt} = x +x^{2020}  \cos(t)$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't tell. Constant shifts don't affect the derivative.

Comment: So, without initial conditions it is not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: You have a quick tutorial that explains how to format the math, Luke. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much this could help you but the differential equation
$$\frac {dx}{dt} = x +x^{n}  \cos(t)$$ has analytical solutions.

$$x=z^{\frac{1}{1-n}}\implies z'=(1-n)z+(1-n)\cos(t)$$ which is easy to integrate using the variation of parameters. This leads to
$$z=c_1 e^{-(n-1)t}+\frac{n-1}{(n-1)^2+1}\big((n-1)\cos(t)+\sin(t)\big)$$

$$x=\Big[c_1 e^{-(n-1)t}+\frac{n-1}{(n-1)^2+1}\big((n-1)\cos(t)+\sin(t)\big) \Big]^{\frac{1}{1-n}}$$